# how to add tabulator columns setting automatically for unkown JSONData

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tabulator

I'm a new dev , i got a Json object that i don't know it's content that i need to add to Tabulator

by definition i need to add details for each columns for example :

```
var JSONData =[{A:12,B:3,C:13},{A:5,B:23,C:3},{A:1,B:30,C:103}]

var tabulator1 = new Tabulator("#table", {
    data:JSONData,
    columns:[
       {title:"A", field:"A", sorter:"string",align:"right", editor:true},
       {title:"B", field:"B", sorter:"string",align:"right", editor:true},
       {title:"C", field:"C", sorter:"string",align:"right", editor:true},
     ],
});
```

it's working now but what if `var JSONData =[UNKNOWN LIST OF JSON DATA ]`

I know how to get headers of the columns by `Object.keys(JSONData[0]));`
I can leave the default definition for the columns like this

```
{title:"A", field:"A", sorter:"string",align:"right", editor:true},
```

but how can i loop through the unkown JSONData and append it to `columns:[]`?

i'll probably just need to at least add title and field data for the tabulator to work properly

another solution :  I can use flask-jinja2 to loop through it from the back end but i don't want to count on the server resources as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me.
This will work if all the elements in the array have the same number of keys.

```
var JSONData =[{A:12,B:3,C:13},{A:5,B:23,C:3},{A:1,B:30,C:103}]

var tabulator1 = new Tabulator("#table", {
  data:JSONData,
  columns:Object.keys(JSONData[0]).map(obj => {
    return {
      title: obj,
      field: obj,
      sorter: "string",
      align: "right",
      editor: true
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The new versions (currently at 5.4) of Tabulator have a feature called `autoColumns` which can be used to generate column names automatically. More information about this feature is here: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/columns#autocolumns